# Centered image over split color background in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background, layer

I've found how to make an image over color background but not when you have two of them. I'd like to center only **one** image in the middle of the screen/page and I want it to shrink with the window size.

**Image example:** 
[image: Example image]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
#top,
#bottom {
  background: url('http://uxrepo.com/static/icon-sets/zocial/svg/chrome.svg') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
#top {
  top: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff38f;
}
.header-container {
  height: 130px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
}
.header {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.footer-container {
  height: 130px;
  width: 99%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="top">
    <div class="header-container">
      <div class="header">
        SOME TITLE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="bottom">

    <div class="footer-container">
      <div class="footer">
        some text
        <br>
        <br>some text
        <br>some text
        <br>some text
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Does anyone know how to make this result simple?

Comment: could you explain a bit more? I don't understand the desired result and what is wrong with the current code?

Comment: The above result splits the image into two parts of the background because I have it in the #top, #bottom {...} but I want only one image to appear on the screen and be centered in the middle of the page.

Comment: An image of the desired result would be helpful and a dd a lot of clarity to the request.

Comment: I've added an image example above in the post.

Answer (score 2):

#### Svg

Since you are using an svg you can simply use that inline.
And if you put it inline like i have done here in the example below.
You can change all colors in the svg with css.

```css
svg {
  height: 100vh;
}
#rect1 {
  fill: firebrick;
}
#rect2 {
  fill: #229;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 400">
    <rect id="rect1" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="200" />
    <rect id="rect2" x="0" y="200" width="1000" height="200" />
    <g transform="translate(150,100) scale(0.2)">
      <path d="M0 523q0-75 23-155.5t62-144.5q62-104 182.5-163.5t248.5-59.5q130 0 249.5 81.5t182.5 201.5q50 86 50 214 0 150-71 266t-192 177-270 60q20-36 61-109.5t73.5-130.5 64.5-108l1-2q3-5 12-18.5t12.5-19.5 9.5-17 9.5-21 5.5-21q6-24 6-48 0-80-48-142l275-81q-285 0-428 1-7-1-22-1-99 0-165.5 74t-55.5 173q-2-9-2-28 0-44 15-77l-204-201 198 341q19 72 79.5 117.5t134.5 45.5q17 0 33-3l-66 276q-115 0-223-71t-175-176q-66-102-66-230zm312-19q0 77 54.5 131.5t130.5 54.5 130.5-54.5 54.5-131.5q0-76-54-130.5t-131-54.5-131 54.5-54 130.5z"
      />
    </g>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, I don't want a fixed width but a dynamic one - width: 100% height: 100%.

Comment: This is an example, ofc you can set the width of your svg to height:100%

Comment: Nono actually I want my split background to be 100%, any idea how to do that on your example?

Comment: You want to use it as a site background?

Comment: Yes both image and color-background.

Comment: Just save the svg part to file and use it as a background.
But just use AlexG solution, then you only have to use a single element and your svg stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Gradient

My approach, with a gradient background: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erbub5xn/)**

```
<div class="background">
    <img src="source"/>
</div>

.background{
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #db6062 0%,#db6062 50%,#db6062 50%,#dae27a 50%,#dae27a 100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.background img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
}
```